# How to run a custom task few times with different parameters?

Tags: ant

I am trying to execute target "MyTarget" and get an error: "Unsupported element echo".  Perhaps Macrodef is not the way to do the job.  Is there any other way to pass a task to another target/macrodef with different parameters?

```
<macrodef name="dotask">
    <attribute name="platform" description="" />
    <attribute name="config" description="" />
    <element name="task2" optional="true" />
    <sequential>
        <task2 />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<macrodef name="buildsuite2">
    <element name="task" optional="true" />
    <sequential>
        <dotask platform="win32" config="debug">
            <task />
        </dotask>   
        <dotask platform="win32" config="release">
            <task />
        </dotask>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

    <target name="MyTarget">
        <buildsuite2>
            <task>
                <echo>${platform} ${config}</echo>
            </task>
        </buildsuite2>
    </target>
```

Answer (score 1):

> How to run a custom task few times with different parameters?

Yes you can do it with help of [antcall](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/antcall.html) task.

The sample:

```
<target name="method_impl">
    <echo message="${firstParam}"/>
    <echo message="${secondParam}"/>
</target>

<target name="test_calling_twice">
    <echo message="First time call"/>
    <antcall target="method_impl">
        <param name="firstParam" value="fP1"/>
        <param name="secondParam" value="sP1"/>
    </antcall>

    <echo message="Second time call"/>
    <antcall target="method_impl">
        <param name="firstParam" value="fP2"/>
        <param name="secondParam" value="sP2"/>
    </antcall>
</target>
```

The output will be:

> First time call 
>   fP1 
>   sP1 
>   Second time call 
>   fP2 
>   sP2

Comment: I have a set of params that will re-use for quite a number custom task.  Doing what you propose may solve the problem but I have to write a antcall for each param set.  If I add a new param set, I have to add a new antcall for each custom task.

Comment: @Chau You could factor out the common code using a [macrodef](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/macrodef.html) and antcall that.